# How can I change date and time using timestamp argument of date function?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

When I use `date()` function to display date, it's not according to local time zone. I want it to be according to the local time zone. Can it be done using the `timestamp` parameter of this function?

Actually I don't know what the `timestamp` parameter is. How do I use it to alter date and time?

Secondly, is there any other function that can set date time according to our time zone?

Here's what I've tried but it's not working:

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "winkcage");
if(isset($_POST["cmessage"])){
$messages=$_POST["cmessage"];
$sender=$_SESSION["unamsession"];
$receiver="vinaykumar";
$timedate=date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
$time=date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$sendquery="INSERT INTO messages(sender, receiver, message, time) VALUES('$sender', '$receiver', '$messages', '$time')";
$sendqueryrun=mysqli_query($conn, $sendquery);
}
?>
```

Comment: Read about \DateTime() php function...

BTW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: [date_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Timestamp** is nothing more then [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) - it's used widely in IT and it's defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

Default value for `timestamp` parameter of `date` function is [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php). If it's not according to your timezone you should change the default timezone using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function. [List of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

**Instead of using function** (if you can edit your `php.ini`) you should set default timezone there. More about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone).

Also, it's better to use [`DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) if you are running PHP >= 5.2. To get current date in your timezone you could create new `DateTime object` with two parameters: first would be current time (you can set it to `now` and it will work) and second being `DateTimeZone object` with timezone name as parameter, list of available timezone names is [available here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). Then you can easily convert it to desired format. Example:

```php
$date = new DateTime( "now", new DateTimeZone( "America/Bogota" ) );
$date = $date->format( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
echo $date; // prints: 2016-04-04 09:07:48
```

### EDIT:

For your code try:

```php
date_default_timezone_set( "Asia/Calcutta" );
$conn = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "winkcage" );
if ( isset( $_POST[ "cmessage" ] ) ){
    $messages = $_POST[ "cmessage" ];
    $sender = $_SESSION[ "unamsession" ];
    $receiver = "vinaykumar";
    $timedate = date( "Y-m-d h:i:sa" );
    $sendquery = "INSERT INTO messages(sender, receiver, message, time) VALUES('$sender', '$receiver', '$messages', '$time')";
    $sendqueryrun = mysqli_query( $conn, $sendquery );
}
```

Or with `DateTime class`:

```php
$conn = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "winkcage" );
if ( isset( $_POST[ "cmessage" ] ) ){
    $messages = $_POST[ "cmessage" ];
    $sender = $_SESSION[ "unamsession" ];
    $receiver = "vinaykumar";
    $date = new DateTime( "now", new DateTimeZone( "America/Bogota" ) );
    $timedate = $date->format( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
    $sendquery = "INSERT INTO messages(sender, receiver, message, time) VALUES('$sender', '$receiver', '$messages', '$time')";
    $sendqueryrun = mysqli_query( $conn, $sendquery );
}
```

Comment: Please check the question details, I've added my code. It's not working. It's storing 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000.

Comment: @VikasKumar Edited answer, try now.

Comment: Also, for future you should read [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) and use those coding styles as it's a standard.

Comment: Can you answer my one more question related to designing? I have a div, and I've set overflow: scroll in CSS. Now, I have a long list in this div. What I want is that when Ioad the page, the last item of the list should be displayed at the bottom and not the first one. I mean the list items on the top should be hidden, similar to Facebook chat.

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't `$timedate` be `$time` or vice versa, you use two different variables for storing/inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka'); //set the time zone
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s A'); //print local time of the current time zone
```

**Update**

Mysql datetime format is 24H. To insert in mysql database,

```
$timedate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');//24H time format
```

Or,

```
$sendquery="INSERT INTO messages(sender, receiver, message, time) VALUES('$sender', '$receiver', '$messages', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($timedate))."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like so:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

var_dump($d);
```

You can also do it in one line, like so:

`$d = new DateTime('', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));`

**Output:**

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-04-04 15:19:35.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/London"
}
```

Comment: Please check the question details, I've added my code. It's not working. It's storing 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000.

Comment: @VikasKumar Looks like you named your variable `$timedate` but inserted a variable called `$time`

Comment: I had already corrected it. The problem was something else that I solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the php.ini file.
Just search `date.timezone` and set it to your timezone.

Go to http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php to search yours.

Or you can use `date_default_timezone_set()`.
For this one, I let you search there : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

For example, if you choose Paris, in the php.ini file it would be :

```
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
```

with the function, it would be :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```

EDIT :
Try this code.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");    
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "winkcage");
if(isset($_POST["cmessage"])){
  $messages=$_POST["cmessage"];
  $sender=$_SESSION["unamsession"];
  $receiver="vinaykumar";
  $timedate=date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
  $sendquery="INSERT INTO messages(sender, receiver, message, time) VALUES('$sender', '$receiver', '$messages', '$timedate')";
  $sendqueryrun=mysqli_query($conn, $sendquery);
}
```

Comment: Please check the question details, I've added my code. It's not working. It's storing 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000.

Comment: You need to use the function at the top of the code. Don't need to put it in a variable. And then you use your date() function. And you need to insert the value affected by the date() function.